# How do I write a Javascript GET request in Firebase Functions?

Tags: javascript, firebase, ecmascript-6, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to write a simple GET request that returns the JSON data at `https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/160705.json`

I have tried a number of things and nothing seems to work. (I'm on the paid Firebase plan that allows requests to external API's). I write the function, then run `firebase deploy` and execute the function but it either times out or throws another error.

As a test, this simple HTTP call works fine:

```
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  response.send('test');
})
```

But when I try to run the following, hitting the HN API, it times out:

```
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  request.get('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/160705.json', function (error, res, body) {
    if (!error && res.statusCode == 200) {
      console.log(body) // Print the google web page.
    }
    return response.send("") // this terminates the function
  })
})
```

**EDIT**

The firebase log for the above function says:
`Function execution started`
`Function execution took 60002 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'`

I've also tried a couple other things, for example:

```
const options = {
  host: 'hacker-news.firebaseio.com',
  path: '/v0/item/160705.json'
};

// make the request
exports.hackerNews = functions.https.onRequest(options, (resp) => {
  console.log(resp)
});
```

but that fails with a 500 `Error: could not handle the request` and `Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade`

It shouldn't be this difficult to write a simple GET request in firebase functions, so I must be doing something dumb. Thanks.

Comment: What does the log say in the Firebase console?

Comment: BTW your second example with `exports.hackerNews` isn't going to work at all. HTTP type functions only take two arguments, an express.js request and response.

Comment: @DougStevenson I edited my question, the log says it timed out.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out:

```
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  request.get('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/160705', (error, response, body) => {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
      return res.send(body);
    }
    return res.send('ERROR: ' + error.message);
  })
});
```

Apparently you have to return something on success or error, you just can't execute another function like console.log().